# Angularjs ui-grid change row background color

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have this code in plunker that I cant make it to work : [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BRgQKUwHGUFpYtm1W258)

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.grid']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

  $scope.myData = [{sv_name: "Moroni", sv_code: 50,count:0},
                 {sv_name: "Tiancum", sv_code: 43,count:1},
                 {sv_name: "Jacob", sv_code: 27,count:0},
                 {sv_name: "Nephi", sv_code: 29,count:7},
                 {sv_name: "Enos", sv_code: 34,count:0}];

   $scope.getBkgColorTable = function (saveStatus) {
                switch (saveStatus) {
                    case -1:
                        return "";
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        return "#dff0d8";
                        break;
                    default:// anything but 0 and -1, alerts
                        return "#f2dede";
                }
            };

  //ng-class="{\'green\':true, \'red\':row.entity.count==0 }"
  var rowtpl='<div><div style="{\'background-color\': getBkgColorTable(myData[row.rowIndex].count)}" ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name" class="ui-grid-cell" ng-class="{ \'ui-grid-row-header-cell\': col.isRowHeader }" ui-grid-cell></div></div>';

  $scope.gridOptions = {
    enableSorting: true,
    data:'myData',

    rowTemplate:rowtpl,
    columnDefs: [
      { field: 'sv_name', displayName: 'Nombre',},
      { field: 'sv_code', displayName: 'Placa'},
      { field: 'count'}
    ]
  };


}]);
```

The idea is to check status field in the grid and change the background color of the grid.

Regards

Carlos

Answer (score 1):

Try change template to this:

```
 var rowtpl='<div><div style="height: 100%; {\'background-color\': getBkgColorTable(myData[row.rowIndex].count)}" ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name" class="ui-grid-cell" ng-class="{ \'ui-grid-row-header-cell\': col.isRowHeader }" ui-grid-cell></div></div>';
```

When div is empty (has no text) its size is zero so it doesn't rendered.